# How do I fix permissions on Big Sur?

Tags: macos, permission, big-sur

I *think* I am experiencing permission problems on my Mac. I am running an iMac with macOS Big Sur, recently updated to 11.4, though the problem has been around for a while.

There is one application which cannot save an existing file (though it can save a new one). As part of the trouble-shooting process, I logged in as an alternative user, and it seems to work properly. I conclude that it has something to do with who can do what.

I have also saved the file to an external USB flash storage, which is in ExFat format. This is from my normal account. Again this works perfectly, so I conclude that saving on a volume with no specific permissions is OK. I doesn’t work if I save to an external drive formatted with HFS+ or APFS.

This leads me to conclude that the problem is one of permissions, possibly on the `~/Library` directory. Comparing permissions on the Home directories, I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 irving     staff    352 27 May 14:32 irving/
drwxr-xr-x@ 97 mark       staff   3104 26 May 09:54 mark/
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 something  staff    416 26 May 09:57 something/
```

The `mark` directory is for my normal account, and the only differences I can see are that final symbol (`+` or `@`).

When I run `ls -l@d /Users/*` I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 irving     staff    352 27 May 15:02 /Users/irving/
drwxr-xr-x@ 97 mark       staff   3104 26 May 09:54 /Users/mark/
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot    50
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot    50
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 something  staff    416 26 May 09:57 /Users/something/
```

What are the correct permissions for a Home directory, and how can I ensure that they are all set correctly?

Output from `ls -l@e /Users/mark*/Downloads/*.lbx`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  1156 21 Mar 09:50 /Users/mark/Downloads/Test Label.lbx
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16
    com.apple.macl    72
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_mfabisnytttdleinsb4kkin77y    89
    com.apple.quarantine      29
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  1641 13 Apr 17:42 /Users/mark/Downloads/Test2.lbx
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16
    com.apple.macl    72
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_mfabisnytttdleinsb4kkin77y    89
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  1150 27 May 16:18 /Users/mark/Downloads/test.lbx
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16
    com.apple.macl    72
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_mfabisnytttdleinsb4kkin77y    89tp
```

Comment: What is the result of ```ls -l@d /Users/*```. For reset permissions on your User Structure you can try this command : ``diskutil resetuserpermissions / `id -u`  ``

Comment: @Jean_JD I have run the command, and the problem persists.

Comment: Ah, so you open a file from ~/Documents and can‘t save it into *any* directory? What application is this?

Comment: @nohillside I can always save as a new document into any directory. I just can’t save an existing document. The software I’m using doesn’t have a `Save As…` option, so it’s a matter of moving the file or renaming it.

Comment: Can you please run `ls -l@e` on one of these files?

Comment: @nohillside `ls -ld@e` gives me `drwx------@ … com.apple.macl … 0: group:everyone deny delete` . Without the `d` I get details for all the subdirectories.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output you get, so we see the full name of the extended attribute and the ACL. Most likely the ACL is the problem here, but this can be easily fixed once we know how it is called.

Comment: @nohillside Sorry, I misunderstood. Did you mean on the individual files which can’t be saved?

Comment: The `ls -ld@e` you run on `Downloads`, right? The ACL there doesn't hurt. But right now I would remove all the metadata attributes from the files in question (`xattr -d com.apple.XXX FILE`, repeat for all four attributes).

Comment: And it might still help to know which application this is :-)

Comment: @nohillside (Should we be doing this in chat?) I have removed the attributes as you suggested, restarted the application, and it still doesn’t save. The application is the Brother P-Touch (Label) Editor. Brother were of no use, suggesting things like making sure the extension (`.lbx`) was added to the file.

Comment: If the problem has been around for a while, what exactly had changed when it started? Did you migrate your Mac, restore from backup, copy these files from an external drive?

Comment: @nohillside I _think_ it’s Big Sur. My own account was migrated from previous versions of macOS (via Time Machine), and the alternative accounts were created recently. I get the impression that the migrated accounts included some permissions baggage.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the result of a poorly completed Time Machine restore

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 97 mark       staff   3104 26 May 09:54 /Users/mark/
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot    50
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot    50
```

You can try this 2 commands for suppress this attributs :

```
xattr -rd com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot /Users/mark
```

and

```
xattr -rd com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot /Users/mark
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it doesn’t seem to help. I was getting a lot of `Permission denied` messages, so I used `sudo`. I then got a lot of `No such file` messages.

Comment: You must start by adding the terminal in the system preferences / Security, Privacy / Privacy / Full access to the disk, then restart the terminal and retry.

Comment: I’ve just done that. I’m still getting the same messages.

Comment: You can try ``sudo chflags -R nouchg  /Users/mark`` and retry. If you have always the error message you can try ``sudo chflags -R noschg  /Users/mark``